# How can I check whether we're using the new Contacts structure in Marketing Cloud?

Tags: marketing-cloud, contact, contactbuilder

[Marketing Cloud Contact Builder documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_cab_getting_started_with_contact_builder.htm&type=5) says '*Account administrators for current accounts can opt to use the new Contacts structure instead of the existing data structure present in their accounts.*'

I'm new to Marketing Cloud (and am an administrator). How can I check to see if we're using the new Contacts structure? Also, if we're not using it, how can we opt to use it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have access to Contact Builder (including a.o. Data Designer seen below), you do have the "new" Contacts structure.

You can find Contact Builder by following these steps:

1. Log in to Marketing Cloud.
2. Locate the primary navigation bar.
3. Hover over **Audience Builder**.
4. Click **Contact Builder**.

Indeed only very old instances of Marketing Cloud are not using this setup, so chances of you being on one of those environments are very slim.

[image]

You can get more insights into Contact Builder features in [this Trailhead module](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/contact-builder-implementation-basics).